# How get old versions from MS SQL Developer Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, license

I'm trying to get SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition but when I access to [Microsoft Dev Essentials page](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads/Featured?mkt=es-es) I only can see Express Edition versions:

[image]

And when I visit [SQL Server Download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) I only can download 2019 version

I would like get previous versions of SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Old versions are not included in the Downloads for Visual Studio Dev Essentials.  You need Visual Studio Professional, or one of the other paid subscriptions to access the back catalog of software.  The complete list of available downloads by subscription type is [here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/5/4/15454442-CF17-47B9-A65D-DF84EF88511B/Visual_Studio_by_Subscription_Level.xlsx).

It is a free license, if you have access to the media.

The SQL Server 2016 Evaluation Edition installer is still available for download [here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/1/A/41AD6EDE-9794-44E3-B3D5-A1AF62CD7A6F/sql16_sp2_dlc/en-us/SQLServer2016SP2-FullSlipstream-x64-ENU.iso), and you can select Developer edition during the install.

Comment: Now do 2005. (yes, I really do need to install SS2005 in 2023, so I can run an old application we having used since 2013 for long enough to get data out of it, and it's not enough just the import the old mdf/ldf files to a newer server: I really do need to run the app. I'm setting up the win7 vm to host it as I type) :(

Comment: SQL Server 2005, even SQL Server 2000 are there on Visual Studio downloads.

Answer (score -3):

have you ever seen this website before :
[image]

[sql server 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/topic/kb5003279-sql-server-versi%C3%B3n-de-service-pack-3-de-2016-46ab9543-5cf9-464d-bd63-796279591c31)

Comment: That's the Service Pack, not the full installer, except for Express Edition, which always gets slipstreamed installers for Service Packs.